# When dependent packages should be recompiled?

Tags: delphi

After recompiling a package, I always recompile all its dependent packages.

Is it really always needed?

For example, does the following actions require the recompilation of the dependent packages?

1. Chaning the `implementation` sections of the package's units, without modifiying any of the interface sections
2. Changing the declaration (in the `interface` section) of a `private`/`protected` function?

Comment: Recompiling dependent packages is only needed if you make changes to `interface` sections, not to `implementation ` sections

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks, and if I add empty spaces or comments in the interface sections?

Comment: I honestly couldn't answer that. One would hope that whitespace and comments are omitted from unit versioning, but I never had need to explicitly test that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Ok, and what if I change, in the interface section, the declaration of a private function? (Probably I'm searching for the wrong keywords, but I have not been able to find any official documentation about that)

Comment: changing ANY declarations in a unit's interface will definitely affect the unit's versioning and require anything dependent on that unit to be recompiled.